# How to implement multiple counter in VueJS

Tags: web, vue.js, web-development-server

I'm a beginner and I'm working on a little exercice right now where I need to implement a function that will vote for a specific picture every time we click on the "Vote" button.

[image]

Here is what it looks like, for example if I click on the first button, I need to increment the number of vote for this picture.
Here is what i did :

```
<div id="display" class="container">
    <table class="w3-table-all" id="tableDisplay">
      <tr>
        <th>Cat</th>
        <th>Vote</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div v-for="display in gridData">
    <table class="w3-striped w3-table-all table table-bordered" id="tableDisplay">
      <tr class="w3-hover-light-grey">
        <th>
          <img :src="display.url" height="200px" width="300px"/>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button class="w3-button w3-green w3-hover-light-green"v-on:click="test(display.counter,display.id)" v-bind:id="display.id">Vote !</button>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</div>
```

And the vueJs part :

```
new Vue({


el :'#display',
  data: {
    gridData :[
    {
        "url": "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m82woaL5AD1rro1o5o1_1280.jpg",
        "id": "MTgwODA3MA",
        "counter" : 0
    },
    {
        "url": "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m29a9d62C81r2rj8po1_500.jpg",
        "id": "tt",
        "counter" : 0

    }
  ],
},
  methods:{
    test: function(count,id){
      count ++;
      alert(count);
    }
  },
})
```

And the problem is that it doesn't update the change, in the "counter" section it still at 0.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<div v-for="display in gridData">` to `<div v-for="(display, idx) in gridData">` so that you know which item in the array you are using.

`v-on:click="test(display.counter,display.id)` to `v-on:click="test(idx)`

and the `test` function to:

```
test: function(idx) {
  this.gridData[idx].count++;
}
```

So that you are incrementing the count of the array item.

Currently you are just incrementing the argument `count` (an instance variable that dies after the scope of `test` ends) which does nothing.

---

See below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#display',
  data: {
    gridData: [{
        "url": "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m82woaL5AD1rro1o5o1_1280.jpg",
        "id": "MTgwODA3MA",
        "counter": 0
      },
      {
        "url": "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m29a9d62C81r2rj8po1_500.jpg",
        "id": "tt",
        "counter": 0
      }
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    test: function(idx) {
      this.gridData[idx].counter++;
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="display" class="container">
  <table class="w3-table-all" id="tableDisplay">
    <tr>
      <th>Cat</th>
      <th>Vote</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div v-for="(display,idx) in gridData">
    <table class="w3-striped w3-table-all table table-bordered" id="tableDisplay">
      <tr class="w3-hover-light-grey">
        <th>
          <img :src="display.url" height="200px" width="300px" />
        </th>
        <th>
          <div>Current Votes: {{display.counter}}</div>
          <button class="w3-button w3-green w3-hover-light-green" v-on:click="test(idx)" v-bind:id="display.id">Vote !</button>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much Sir ! The only problem is that it doesn't save the number of vote (if I refresh the page, it goes back to 0). I would like it to update the value in JS file. Do you know if it is possible ? Thank you

Comment: @VincentTng That is a big question with a big answer.  You should look into persisting data.  If you want **all** visitors to your site to see the **same** votes you'll need server side persistence.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I tried to code using the methods localStorage.getItem (i heard it would work) but I'm a complete beginner and I don't understand how it work. Do you minds checking my code really quick ?. I don't really know how to use it. I have created another post on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870263/saving-data-locally-in-vuejs.          If you have any suggestion, I would be really grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Repeated elements with functionality like this is where components are really handy. Break the individual item display into its own sub-component, like this:

```
<div v-for="display in gridData">
    <vote-widget :picture="display"></vote-widget>
</div>
```

Each one will have its own data and isolated scope.